# Borked my Cyanogenmod installation - please help! (LG Nexus 5x)

Tags: cyanogenmod, installation, nexus-5x, nexus

This was totally my fault but now I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I just bought 2 nexus 5x phones and planned to install Cyanogenmod 13 on each. I succeeded on the first attempt but this is what happened on the second:

I forgot to re-enable USB debugging after unlocking the bootloader but managed to proceed with installing twrp and vendor.img. When it came time to push (adp push) cm13 to /sdcard, adp gave me this error: "adp: error: connect failed: no devices/emulators found". "fastboot devices" shows that the phone is connected and the recover mode screen shows fastboot mode. (install instructions: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_bullhead).

I can get into twrp but trying to boot the phone normally does not work. I get an error saying that the device is corrupted, and then the boot hangs at the weird google animated logo. The screen never shuts off and the animated logo just keeps going around and around.

I can't do a hard reset because I keep ending up at twrp when I try to follow the hard reset instructions.

What should me next steps be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flash it again using twrp. Also you can do a hard reset with twrp to

Comment: I can't because I don't have CM13 on the device - I was trying to put it there using adb when the whole thing fell apart.

Answer (score 0):

You have ended up in a bootloop... But that shouldn't be a problem, just flash CM 13 again. You don't even need to have adb access, you can just put the files on an external SDCard (using a card reader for your PC), put the SDCard into your device and flash the files using the recovery.

Comment: I thought about that, too, but the Nexus 5x doesn't have an SD card slot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  As usual, a good night's sleep and some googling helped me find a solution:

I followed the instructions from Google itself to completely reinstall the factory image:

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Lack of hyperactive kids (the root cause of my initial mistake) allowed me to carefully follow the instructions.

Now my phone is back in its original state - except that I chose the factory image that matches the version of Cyanogenmod I want to install - and I can start the process over.

Thanks again.